# Convert nested subdocuments to individual documents MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am emulating Firebase Realtime DB's RestFul API.
Since there is no standard data structure followed when the data is uploaded.

I have encountered a complication where I want to split a nested document into documents to perform further sorting aggregation on it using mongo-query instead of the server.

Below is the data I have extracted using `$project`

```json
{
  "data": {
    "8787879798": {
      "value": 89
    },
    "c5ca5ebd804b4b1aab82348a4070fa78": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "88dc2f042c3e4aa3a2a2378e48444000": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "7061e88f77754b6e94b3b2ed3bf7513f": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "033f120577c443548d4cdc4425a7767f": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "33fb18ba5e3d41c5a6b9b89433ab231d": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "5f9c6d4bf0e3416b9b963dbf5d15021d": {
      "sample": 78
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the query

```json
[
  {
    $project:
      /**
       * specifications: The fields to
       *   include or exclude.
       */
      {
        _id: 0,
        data: "$foo.bar.xyz",
      },
  },
]
```

Want to get an output like this:

> Where every subdocument becomes a document

```json
{
    "8787879798": {
      "value": 89
    },
    "c5ca5ebd804b4b1aab82348a4070fa78": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "88dc2f042c3e4aa3a2a2378e48444000": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "7061e88f77754b6e94b3b2ed3bf7513f": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "033f120577c443548d4cdc4425a7767f": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "33fb18ba5e3d41c5a6b9b89433ab231d": {
      "sample": 78
    },
    "5f9c6d4bf0e3416b9b963dbf5d15021d": {
      "sample": 78
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$replaceRoot` stage in the pipeline, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZF8cUs1-dxC)

Comment: Thanks!! This works...
But I wasn't able to generalize this for random data schemas. There happens to a document that is found when queried on the root, which just doesn't fit the generic query when combined with additional filtering done in python. Finally, have chosen a different way to model data so as make full use of multiple collections and aggregation queries.

Comment: This is not a generalized solution, depending on the structure, the query might vary. If your schema is completely random, it's better to normalize it at application level, rather than db level.

Comment: Yeah! Agreed...
That's what I am saying. Modifying the data model so that it can be generalized at an application level.

Comment: Yeah, I got it.